# Drawing Boxplot in Matplotlib using float64 data type

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm trying to draw a Boxplot using Matplotlib for the 'size' column but I can't draw because of some errors I don't know.[Other columns such as price, number rooms, current_energy_efficiency I can draw well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgkbU.png) but not size. I thought it related to data type, because the ones I can draw all are 'int64', [while the data type for size is 'float64'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByhSW.png).

[After that, I change data type into 'int64'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS7An.png) but [it still give back error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk8s4.png) [TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGZci.png). How should I fix the size to being able to draw Boxplot? [The data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxuG0.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide all the relevant code and error messages as text, [rather than using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: You should write `asm['size']` because `asm.size` would just calculate the dataframe's size.  Please take into account that questions need reproducible code and errors in text format, never as image.